# Issue with str_to_date() function with Empty field

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, pymysql, str-to-date

In python, I am trying to insert some data into my table;

```
   try:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO covid_testtable (pid, age, state, city, notes, backnotes, type, nationality, status, announced, changed) " +
                "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, STR_TO_DATE(%s, '%%d/%%m/%%Y'), STR_TO_DATE(%s, '%%d/%%m/%%Y'))",
            (pid, age, item["detectedstate"], item["detectedcity"], item["notes"], item["backupnotes"], item["typeoftransmission"],
                item["nationality"], item["currentstatus"], dateannounced, statuschanged));
    except ValueError as verr:
        print(item["dateannounced"], verr);
        break;
```

This works till a point where one of the date columns have a empty entry.

```
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1411, "Incorrect datetime value: '' for function str_to_date"
```

I tried to change the value of the empty date to "**00/00/0000**" however it seems the issue is with the **str_to_date**() function.
I am fine with inserting **NULL** value however, not managing to insert.

The valid values which are succesfully inserted are of this format "**30/01/2020**" -> "**%d/%m/%Y**"

My table schema is as below:

```
create table covid_testtable ( pid int NOT NULL, age int, state VARCHAR(255), 
city VARCHAR(255), notes VARCHAR(255), backnotes VARCHAR(255), type VARCHAR(255), 
nationality VARCHAR(255), status VARCHAR(255), announced DATE default NULL, 
changed DATE default NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (pid));
```

**EDIT 2: Selected Answer solved this issue:**

```
def validate_date(val):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(val, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
    except ValueError as verr:
        return None;

    dateannounced = validate_date(item["dateannounced"]);
    statuschanged = validate_date(item["statuschangedate"]);
    try:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO covid_testtable (pid, age, state, city, notes, backnotes, type, nationality, status, announced, changed) " +
                "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
            (pid, age, item["detectedstate"], item["detectedcity"],
                item["notes"], item["backupnotes"], item["typeoftransmission"],
                item["nationality"], item["currentstatus"], dateannounced,
                statuschanged));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than processing the dates in the query, you could pre-process them in your python code. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

dstr = ''
try:
    dateannounced = datetime.strptime(dstr, '%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
except ValueError:
    dateannounced = None
```

Then your query simply becomes

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO covid_testtable (pid, age, state, city, notes, backnotes, type, nationality, status, announced, changed) " +
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
              (pid, age, item["detectedstate"], item["detectedcity"], 
               item["notes"], item["backupnotes"], item["typeoftransmission"],
               item["nationality"], item["currentstatus"], dateannounced, 
               statuschanged));
```

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the string is empty with `if()`.

```
cursor.execute("""
    INSERT INTO covid_testtable (pid, age, state, city, notes, backnotes, type, nationality, status, announced, changed)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, 
            IF(%s = '', NULL, STR_TO_DATE(%s, '%%d/%%m/%%Y')), 
            IF(%s = '', NULL, STR_TO_DATE(%s, '%%d/%%m/%%Y')))""",
    (pid, age, item["detectedstate"], item["detectedcity"], item["notes"], item["backupnotes"], item["typeoftransmission"],
        item["nationality"], item["currentstatus"], dateannounced, dateannounced, statuschanged, statuschanged));
```

Note that I had to repeat `dateannounced` and `statuschanged` in the parameter list, since I'm substituting them into the `IF` functions in addition to the `STR_TO_DATE` functions.

Comment: When you tried to copy my answer, you forgot to put `dateannounced` and `statuschanged` twice in the parameter list.

Comment: Oh, I just took the IF statements from your answer, My bad. Will update the edit.

Comment: I take partial blame, I should have explained what I was doing more fully.